# Are the extension-guides for vscode open source?

Tags: macos, ntfs

How can I use a micro SD card on mac (MacOS Big Sur 11.4 (20F71))?
I've tried `chmod 777 on both /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/yp-storage`.
I could fix an example to construct `mount -uw`...

Weird why Apple doesn't solve it out of the box...

```
yanivper@Yp-Mac-Pro /Volumes/yp-storage: clear; diskutil info disk2s1

   Device Identifier:         disk2s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk2

   Volume Name:               yp-storage
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /Volumes/yp-storage

   Partition Type:            Windows_NTFS
   File System Personality:   ExFAT
   Type (Bundle):             exfat
   Name (User Visible):       ExFAT

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Volume UUID:               31B27C88-F9B1-395E-83AF-EB9DCA0A15BD

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Yes (read-only mount flag set)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Removable
   Media Removal:             Software-Activated

   Solid State:               Info not available

yanivper@Yp-Mac-Pro /Volumes/yp-storage: mkdir Photos                
mkdir: Photos: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out all you need to do is provide an absolute path (I was trying with relative path).

`sudo mount -uw /Volumes/yp-storage`